Set environment variable in wix bundle installer
I have a bundle installer that installed two of my msi packages and two third party installer. For the third party installer rabbitmq I want to set the environment variable RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT but I am not sure how. I found in other threads, that i can set the environment variable in my msi installer, that is called in my bundle installer but that is not what I want. The two installer require rabbitmq to run and if I first install my two installer to set the RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT then the services of the two installer will stop due to missing rabbitmq.
Code Example:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Foo" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Bar"
            UpgradeCode="3a1fef0b-d0b3-4cbe-a1a8-b1d1c00079e7">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                LicenseUrl=""/>
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
        <Variable Name="RBMQPORT" bal:Overridable="yes"/>

        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="Dotnet"/>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="RabbitMQ"/>

            <MsiPackage Id="FirstAPI" SourceFile="../firstinstaller.msi">
                <MsiProperty Name="RBMQPORT" Value="[RBMQPORT]"/>
            </MsiPackage>

            <MsiPackage Id="SecondAPI" SourceFile="../secondinstaller.msi">
                <MsiProperty Name="RBMQPORT" Value="[RBMQPORT]"/>
            </MsiPackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
      <PackageGroup Id="Dotnet">
            <ExePackage Id="AspNetCoreRuntime"
                        DisplayName="ASP.NET Core Runtime 8.0.4"
                        Compressed="yes"  
                        Cache="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Protocol="netfx4"
                        Vital="yes"
                        SourceFile=".\prerequisites\dotnet-hosting-8.0.4-win.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/passive /norestart /silent" />
            <ExePackage Id="DotnetDesktopRuntime"
                        DisplayName=".NET Desktop Runtime 8.0.4"
                        Compressed="yes" 
                        Cache="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Protocol="netfx4"
                        Vital="yes"
                        SourceFile=".\prerequisites\windowsdesktop-runtime-8.0.4-win-x64.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/passive /norestart /silent" />
        </PackageGroup>
        <PackageGroup Id="RabbitMQ">
            <ExePackage Id="ErlangFramework"
                        DisplayName="Erlang Framework 26.2.5"
                        Compressed="yes"  
                        Cache="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Protocol="netfx4"
                        Vital="yes"
                        SourceFile=".\prerequisites\otp_win64_26.2.5.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/passive /norestart /silent" />
            <ExePackage Id="RabbitMQServer"
                        DisplayName="RabbitMQ Server 3.13.6"
                        Compressed="yes" 
                        Cache="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Protocol="netfx4"
                        Vital="yes"
                        SourceFile=".\prerequisites\rabbitmq-server-3.13.6.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/passive /norestart /silent" />
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>


I tried to add a variable with the Environment element, but this has to be in a component and needs a directory. But here i don't need or have any directory.
      <Component Id="foo">
        <Environment Id="bar" Name="RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT" Value="5673" Permanent="yes" Action="set"/>
      </Component>


Bundles install packages (like MSIs). Packages install resources like files, registry keys and environment variables.

Thank you. So that means i have to make a dedicated installer for rabbitmq if i want to give it a custom port via environment variable. thank you
